# Python lxml validation offline yields "connection refused" to http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2

Tags: python, xsd, gis, lxml, offlineapps

I am trying to validate some XML via lxml and an xsd
(ogckml22.xsd). This is happening OFFLINE. I read ther
file via a straight open/read

For the record,  http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 is not valid.

from another article:
(clarified due to comment request..)

```
from lxml import etree
import os
import sys
import StringIO
file=open('ogckml22.xsd')
data=file.read()
str=StringIO.StringIO(data)
try:
     xmlschema_doc=etree.parse(data)
except IOError as ex:
    print "oops {0}".format(ex.strerror)
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]

xmlschema=etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
```

All I get is a  "connection refused".
With the try/except, I get the xmlschema_doc is not defined.

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
File "<xmlschema.pxi",line 105, in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:132748  
   self.error_log)  
lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: connection refused
```

I know it can read the xsd file above and another xsd file that
gets included.

OK maybe the xsd gets read? I downloaded the source for lxml and in src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi,

```
if self._c_schema is NULL:
    raise XMLSchemaParseError(
        self.error_log._buildExceptionMessage(
            u"Document is not valid XML Schema"),
        self._error_log)
```

I never see the "Document is not valid XML Schema" message. I can only assume that "Connection Refused" is used in place of the "Document message" (a default?) but
a more thorough reading of _error_log (outside of recompilation) evades me....

Sincerely,

ArrowInTree

Comment: Could you provide a minimal complete example that reproduces the problem? What is your `lxml.etree.__version__`?

Comment: Umm, print lxml.etree.__version__ claims 'lxml' is not defined but "print etree.__version__" yields "2.3.3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ogckml22.xsd](http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd) imports two other schema documents (atom-author-link.xsd and xAL.xsd):

```
<!-- import atom:author and atom:link -->
<import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
        schemaLocation="atom-author-link.xsd"/>

<!-- import xAL:Address -->
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0" 
        schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/election/external/xAL.xsd"/>
```

If you want to parse the schema offline, you need to have both these documents available locally and he paths given by `schemaLocation` must be correct.

The parsing and loading of the schema can be simplified (there is no need for `StringIO`):

```
from lxml import etree

xmlschema_doc = etree.parse("ogckml22.xsd") 
xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)

print xmlschema
```

Output:

```
<lxml.etree.XMLSchema object at 0x00D25120>
```

---

I don't understand what you mean by "For the record, http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 is not valid".

If you have internet access, you can use the URL as argument to `etree.parse()`:

```
xmlschema_doc = etree.parse("http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2")
```

At least this works for me.

Comment: Umm, thanks for your help but the *.xsd files you referenced are in the same directory as the script and despite all sorts of twiddling with xmlcatalog on that fc17 box, I get the same message.

Comment: So you are using an XML catalog? You did not say anything about that in the question. It is hard to help if you don't provide all details necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: xmlcatalog only entered the scene AFTER you posted your answer, not before. As I said, all the xsd files are in the same directory as the script, therefore this should be irrelevant.

Comment: Did you change `schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/election/external/xAL.xsd"` to `schemaLocation="xAL.xsd"`?

Comment: Yes, that did work. Thank you. But the point of header files and xsd is a common frame of reference. Sigh.... Know any good tutorials on xmlcatalog...?<br> I have http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/www.sagehill.net/xml/docbookxsl/Catalogs.html (it does go into system vs uri though)

Comment: lxml is based on libxml2, so this document should help a bit, I hope: http://xmlsoft.org/catalog.html. Another good article (more Java-oriented but with some useful general information) is http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html. If you have problems getting it to work, I might be able to help. But I think you should ask a new question in that case.

Comment: One small question: I got xmlcatalog to accept all 3 xsd's as SYSTEM entries. But resolve still does not work... what is the resolution process...?

Comment: I was able to make it work using the `<uri name="uri" uri="alternateuri"/>` construct. See https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/14809/xml-catalogs.html#s.uri.

Comment: I followed the link and tried to duplicate Section 4.3 but xmlcatalog's debug command and error messages are worse than worthless. I tried both rewriteUri and uri entries. Neither worked.

Comment: Sorry to harp on this, but you should submit a new question if you need help with setting up/debugging XML catalogs.